# ATG - Error on starting publishing server

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I've installed and configured **ATG** on my system. I'm using the following configuration for the publishing and production servers:

**Publishing**

- HTTP Port: 8180
- HTTPS Port: 8543
- Site HTTP Port: 8180
- RMI Port: 8861
- DRP Port: 8851
- File Deployment: 8811

**Production**

- HTTP Port: 8080
- HTTPS Port: 8443
- Site HTTP Port: 8080
- RMI Port: 8860
- DRP Port: 8850
- File Deployment: 8810

After running the `startServerOnJBoss.bat` of my production server, it starts its services. The problem is when I run publishing's `startServerOnJBoss.bat`: it shows, immediately this error:

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No Transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Port 8080 is a very common port to be used. Are there any other java processes running? Perhaps another JBoss or Tomcat instance running? That is where I would start.

Comment: Now I put `DEBUG_MODE=false` on **JBoss' standalone.bat** and the publishing server started. The `DEBUG_PORT`, however, is 8787, so I don't know where the conflict is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your production and publishing server are using the same port for debugging. In your **jboss_home/bin** directory, you have **run.conf** file which has this line setting your debugging port **8787** which will conflict.

`set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"`

To use different ports, just make a copy of **run.bat** and **run.conf** bat and rename it, and start your publishing server.
Make sure to change the debugging port for publishing server.